# What is the meaning of installing a setup internally ? Is it copying some file to the drive or what?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am really confused when I install a setup then what it internally does? When I make a setup file(msi) using wix, I just put required file to be copied in a specified location to execute the process and set shortcut,start up link in the XML. Without copying does it any more when I install any windows service or other .exe file?

Comment: That's too big a subject for a reasonable answer. Yes, it copies files, registers services, installs files in the GAC, Programs&Features entries, COM etc, and WiX has some extra functionalty like common actions that people often require,  so read about Windows Installer for the overview. If you have a specific question about one thing that would work a lot better.

Comment: Windows Installer is a component manager. It installs or removes components (file and registry entries) that can be shared by one or more features in one or more versioned products (aka installers). How it does it it is only accessible through the Windows Installer API.